# Подсветка выбора независимо от фокуса в CListCtrl MFC

Tags: mfc

Доброго времени суток. Как в элементе CListCtrl настроенного на Report(т.е. имеется таблица) оставлять выбор всегда? Независимо от фокуса.

Вроде как с этим должен справляться этот код:

```
DWORD ExStyle = CList_Clients->GetExtendedStyle();
ExStyle |= LVS_SHOWSELALWAYS;
CList_Clients->SetExtendedStyle(ExStyle);
```

Но он приводит только к тому что выбор строки перемещается вслед за курсором - т.е. подсвечена строка над которой курсор. Странно...

Так как все же это осуществить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В редакторе ресурсов можно задать свойство "Always show selection". Так при потере фокуса, выбор остается, но лишь слегка заметным. Т.е. в фокусе он подсвечивается синим, а не в фокусе светло-серым.

Вопрос можно закрывать. Хотя странность вышеприведенного кода остается...

Answer (score 0):

Странности нет, т.к. `LVS_SHOWSELALWAYS` (№ 8) не `Extended` стиль, а `Extended` стиль №8 - `LVS_EX_TRACKSELECT`